# If $A \leq B$, $B \leq \overline{A}$, and $B$ is r.e., is $A$ recursive?

Tags: computability

We know that $A ≤ B$, $B ≤ \overline{A}$ and $B$ is recursively enumerable. Is $A$ recursive or not?

I tried negating whats given, but didn't achieve much. I know that from the very first inequality that $A$ is also recursively enumerable. I assumed whether $B$ is also recursive or not to maybe get to a contradiction of some sort, but I always ended up with "sometimes recursive, sometimes not".

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $A \leq B \leq \overline{A}$. Since $B$ is r.e., $A$ is r.e., hence $\overline{A}$ is co-r.e. Since $A \leq \overline{A}$, $A$ is also co-r.e. Hence $A$ is recursive.

Comment: I haven't heard the last rule you make your conclusion with. Can you link me to a proof of or show me how from A≤Ā follows that A is co-r.e. when Ā is co-r.e.

Comment: It's exactly the same proof for the rule with r.e.

Comment: @SimeonValchev One line proof by using the rule with r.e: If L < K, then $\overline{L}$ < $\overline{K}$. If K is co-r.e., then $\overline{K}$ is r.e., so $\overline{L}$ is r.e., and thus L is co-r.e.